# Powershell Wscript.Shell Popup Timeout Does not Timeout

Tags: vba, powershell

I was using `$wshell.Popup($time, $time, 'Warning', 48 + 4096)` for a popup that timesout. Everything worked well when i was writing the code with a timeout of 5 but when i went in production it failed te work with longer timeouts. So i wrote the code below to illustrate the strange behavior. Values over 19 seconds do not work on my computer. Does anyone experience the same problem? How to fix this issue?

(I have PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171 & VBScript.5.8.16384)

```
$time = 1
$increment = 1
$Exclamation = 48
$ShowOnTop = 4096
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
while($true){
    $start = get-date
    $null = $wshell.Popup($time, $time, 'Warning', $Exclamation + $ShowOnTop)
    $delta = (get-date) - $start
    write-host "pop up $time took $($delta.TotalSeconds)" -ForegroundColor Green
    $time += $increment
}
```

Outputs:

```
pop up 1 took 1.1034666
pop up 2 took 2.1012811
pop up 3 took 3.1027432
pop up 4 took 4.1011674
pop up 5 took 8.8805263
pop up 6 took 6.1285214
pop up 7 took 13.8968735
pop up 8 took 8.1029593
pop up 9 took 11.9174401
pop up 10 took 19.0161058
pop up 11 took 19.0150746
pop up 12 took 19.0156603
pop up 13 took 19.0159296
pop up 14 took 19.030777
pop up 15 took 19.0175581
pop up 16 took 19.0388007
pop up 17 took 19.0392871
pop up 18 took 19.043456
pop up 19 did not end after 270 seconds...
```

As a test to isolate the problem i created this vbs file. Which succesfully timesout after 30 seconds:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Hello!", 30, "Title", 4144
```

Comment: PowerShell 5.1.19041.906 here, can't reproduce. (WshShell is a COM object, so the PowerShell version should be quite unrelated to its behavior)

Comment: ...in other words, can you write the same thing in VBScript and see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: version: VBScript.5.8.16384 I tried to create a vbs file with the similar code and that code works. i updated my question above. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. Whether VBScript uses COM to interact with the WshShell object, or Powershell uses COM to interact with the WshShell object makes no difference whatsoever, as far as the WshShell object is concerned. There's literally no reason why this would fail, and fail at a certain "seconds" value at that. But in the interest of moving on, you could consider switching to [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box). A simple timed dialog box should be doable with comparatively little effort.

Comment: Using the same PS version, I changed the first parameter of the PopUp method to `$time.ToString()` and for me that works correctly.

Comment: Interesting... method parameter types are dictated by the COM interface descriptions and should be converted automatically, so this should not make a difference.

Comment: @Theo for me it still does not work with .tostring()

Comment: Weird that it works for me then... Did you try closing PowerShell and reopening it? Your code doesn't show you release the COM object from memory anywhere

Comment: The computer shuts down after the pop up, so i am not to worried about releasing the com object. What i am worried about is that im starting to learn vba... :p So I used a workarround. Thank for the help tough!

Comment: I guess this is a `Wscript.Shell.Popup` bug, see also: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/58jjmy/objshellpopup_does_not_automatically_close_the/