# "CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "strMsg", 5" does not close after 5 seconds

Tags: vba, wsh, wscript.shell

Windows 10, Office 2003 the following code puts up msg box that goes away with no user input after 5 seconds

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "strMsg", 5
```

but after moving to Windows 11/Office 2019 the msgbox no longer goes away automatically. The user has to select the OK button. I thought his was working in his environment but today it's not working.

Is there something that I need to do?

I was expecting a msgbox that would be displayed for 5 seconds and then go away with no user intervention.

Comment: What application are you running this code in within Office?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67330165/11683?

Comment: Welcome Philip! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: @user10186832 I haven't, there isn't even an answer posted there. Just some considerations.

Comment: There’s an interesting [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365470/timeout-msgbox-popup#comment101490484_23367082) that explains how the timeout in Office VBA doesn’t always work. It also, points to [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837192/692942) using `mshta` that acts as a workaround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Close InfoBox.Popup on Timer Expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141775/how-to-close-infobox-popup-on-timer-expiration)

Comment: As you’re using VBA you also have the advantage of being [able to call the Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512186/692942) to do exactly what you want without needing workarounds from external shell calls and COM components.